# Linux: group disappeared from user's group list - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-management, groups

I'm on `Ubuntu 16.04` server edition. I had my user added to `dokku` group 2 days ago just to do periodical postgres backup without needing provide password in cron. 
I've added user to `dokku` group by this command:

```
sudo usermod -aG dokku myuser
```

Backup files was properly generated every hour.... but tonight all generated files are empty - **what I had noticed that user is no longer in `dokku` group**. Adding user to `dokku` group again helps, but I don't know what could be the reason of disappearing `dokku` group from user's groups list ?

Answer (score 0):

After deep investigation of logs I've found the problem:

I've installed dokku plugin for letsencrypt and installation process removed my user from `dokku` group. I was able to replicated this on my other server and here is what happens:

```
> groups myuser
myuser sudo docker dokku

> sudo dokku plugin:install https://github.com/dokku/dokku-letsencrypt.git
...
Adding user dokku to group adm
... other plugin installation info

> groups myuser
myuser sudo docker
```

I've shared this info on dokku channel for further investigation.
Hope it will be helpful for others who experienced this problem.